# Get custom fields value on archive page

Tags: wordpress, archive

I want to display "Custom Field Value" in a archive page for wordpress. I tried
`<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'field_name',true); ?>` but data can not display on archive page. what can i do?

Comment: Are you getting a Error message? Or are you using a plugin for this?

Answer (score -1):

**Add this code your related page of archive.**

```
<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'field_name',true); ?>
```

I have tested both code working fine. Please add code on archive.php just after while loop for test.

Comment: I tried that but it can not working. pls give me other solution. Thank u